# INDEX/MATCH approximate match without sorting

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Let's assume a simple table:

[image]

I would like to find provider name for a given person_id before a specified date.  For example if I specify 1/1/2015 the output should be "Third".

[image]

It's easy enough to do so if the table is sorted by person_id and descending by the status date (as on the picture above), but is there a way to do it without sorting the table in any way?

Comment: Do you have a version of excel that supports Dynamic Arrays?

Comment: A provider at any point before a specified date, or the most-recent provider before a specified date?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - sadly I'm not so lucky.

Comment: How about `MaxIfS`?

Comment: As pseudo code `index ( provider, match ( maxifs ( status_date, person_id, = reqd person, status_date <= reqd date ), status_date, exact match ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest date before the specified for person can be found by the following array formula:

```
{=INDEX(Table2[provider],MATCH(1,--(MAX(((A20=Table2[person_id])*(B20>Table2[status_date])*(Table2[status_date])))=Table2[status_date])*(A20=Table2[person_id]),0))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but you might investigate Power Query and this link:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-pass-parameters-to-my-SQL-statement/td-p/118716

(Courtesy of Greg_Deckler - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-pass-parameters-to-my-SQL-statement/td-p/118716)

Essentially, the premise is to use Power Query to "build/extract" a sub-table (and sort it) on the fly...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am looking for.